# SQL Scalar-Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, user-defined-functions

I am looking to retrieve a value of the profit (FilmBoxOfficeDollar - FilmBudgetDollars) based on the Studio given as a parameter to the function.

```
USE Movies;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnmovieProfits(@StudioName nvarchar(255))
  RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT SUM(FilmBoxOfficeDollars - FilmBudgetDollars)
      FROM Film JOIN Studio
      ON Film.FilmStudioID = Studio.StudioID
      WHERE StudioName = @StudioName);  
END;

GO
SELECT [dbo].[fnmovieProfits]('Dreamworks');
```

Whenever I run this through to pull the piece of data I get the following error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The Return is an `int` data type. Try declaring a variable to put the `SUM()` into first then Return the variable. Is `FilmBoxOfficeDollar` and `FilmBudgetDollars` both datatype `int`?

Comment: Actually looking closer, You need an `AS` after the `RETURNS int` and before the `BEGIN`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thanks for the repsonse! Yeah both `FilmBoxOfficeDollars` and `FilmBudgetDollars` are `int` data types. I also added the `AS` now.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I tried using `DECLARE` to set a variable and then `SET` it = to `FilmBoxOfficeDollars - FilmBudgetDollars` but for some reason am receiving an error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is exceeding `int` range. You should define your return type as `bigint`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnmovieProfits(@StudioName nvarchar(255))
  RETURNS bigint
AS.......
```

The maximum value you can return with `int` as a return type is `2147483647`. Your `sum` is probably bigger than that.

One example of function that exceeds its return type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION testFunction()
  RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT 2147483647 + 1);  
END;

GO
SELECT [dbo].[testFunction]();
```

If you execute it you will get the following error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

So the solution is just to increase your return type range by replacing `int` with `bigint`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are overflowing the allowed value of a 32 bit number (INT); if you cast/convert to a 64 bit number (BIGINT) and return that datatype, the issue will be corrected. Proof of concept showing the issue:

```
DECLARE @BigNumber INT=2000000000
select CONVERT(BIGINT,@BigNumber) + CONVERT(BIGINT,@BigNumber) --returns 4,000,000,000
select (@BigNumber + @BigNumber) --errors with "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."
```

**BUT**, do yourself a favor and use a view instead. Scalars like that are terrible for performance in reports. Scalar functions should never be used unless they are simply doing calculations based on input values (i.e. not hitting underlying, persisted data).

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.v_StudioProfits
AS
   SELECT
      StudioName,
      SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT,FilmBoxOfficeDollars) - CONVERT(BIGINT,FilmBudgetDollars)) AS [Profit]
   FROM Film
   INNER JOIN Studio ON Film.FilmStudioID = Studio.StudioID
   GROUP BY StudioName
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.v_StudioProfits WHERE StudioName='Dreamworks'
```

Relevant [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on SQL Server datatypes. Specifically, [integer datatypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).